# On File read/open provide output from an ready running program

Tags: java, c, linux, debian-based

Running Debian 7.
Is it possible that when a program opens a file we can give it output from a currently running file.

Example:
We have a C/Java program running. This is (attached)? to file /etc/motd as an example.
When ssh or any other program goes to read /etc/motd the C/Java program provides output instead. So instead of the file being read from disk it is being read from the C/Java program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would create /etc/motd as a special device file, not as a regular text or binary file.  Then, you would attach your program to the device file with a pipe and have it waiting for input.  Once input was received the program would then process the data and do the commands required. Items to refer to are: mknod and | (pipe).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in right direction, will invertigate these commands and reply with an example for future reference.